Mysql query for the below result - not returning the result as expected
Table A
Token
AA
BB
CC
DD

Table B
TableA_Token    Key         Value
AA              Method      Virtual
AA              App         Y
AA              Manual      Y
AA              Stored      N
BB              Method      Physical
BB              App         Y
BB              Manual      Y
BB              Stored      N
CC              Method      Virtual
CC              App         N
CC              Manual      N
CC              Stored      N
DD              Method      Virtual
DD              App         N
DD              Manual      N
DD              Stored      N

select a.token
from TableA a
left join TableB b on b.TableA_Token = a.Token 
where
(b.key = 'Method' and b.value = 'Virtual') and
(b.key in ('App', 'Manual', 'Stored') and b.value = 'N');

Need to retrieve all the tokens where method is Virtual and the value for all of these 3 keys (App, Manual, Stored) is N.
Result:
CC
DD

The above query is not returning the data as expected.

How can b.key be both Method and also IN ('App', 'Manual', 'Stored') for the same row? Did you mean to use OR instead of AND?

Join with a subquery that checks whether all the other keys have the value N.
SELECT a.token
FROM TableA AS a
JOIN TableB AS b1 on b1.TableA_Token = a.token
JOIN (
    SELECT TableA_Token
    FROM TableB
    WHERE key IN ('App', 'Manual', 'Stored') AND value = 'N'
    GROUP BY TableA_Token
    HAVING COUNT(*) = 3
) AS b2 ON b2.TableA_Token = a.token
WHERE b1.key = 'Method' AND b1.value = 'Virtual'

